# S’inscrire vs s’abonner vs s’enregistrer

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage

Je suis troublée par ces trois verbes.

Après avoir cherché les sens de ces mots, je pense que :

- S’inscrire s’applique à —> une université, internet ou une application comme YouTube et Google (dont on se sert en payant ou pas)
- S’abonner s’applique à —> un journal, un magazine (dont on se sert toujours en payant et d'où on obtient quelques informations)

-Et quant à s’enregistrer, ce mot s’utilise comme s’inscrire ?

Pourriez-vous m’expliquer s’il vous plaît ?

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,

Dans les faits, au niveau des sites Web et autres applications, "s'inscrire" et "s'enregistrer" peuvent être utilisés sans trop de discernement. J'ai même quelques fois vu "s'abonner" utilisé dans ce genre de contexte, mais bien plus rarement (et ça tient effectivement de la faute).

La différence est plus prégnante dans la vraie vie, où ces trois termes revêtent des sens bien différents :

- S'inscrire : effectivement, on s'inscrit quelque part pour en faire partie et en tirer quelque chose. Dans la pratique, c'est assez proche de "s'enregistrer" au niveau du sens, la principale différence étant que ce n'est pas le terme consacré (on dira assez peu "je me suis enregistré à l'université" même si en fait ça ne pose pas vraiment de problème).
- S'enregistrer : la nuance avec "s'inscrire" peut être une nuance de durée. Un enregistrement me semble plus ponctuel, par exemple "s'enregistrer à l'aéroport pour son vol". Son sens peut souvent se chevaucher avec celui d'"inscrire" ; ainsi, on pourra dire "je me suis inscrit/enregistré dans une base de données".
- S'abonner : implique une notion d'entretien, d'interaction régulière (prélèvement sur compte bancaire, envoi de quelque chose à intervalle régulier ou en permanence...). Attention, l'abonnement n'est ni forcément payant (on s'abonne à des newsletters, des flux RSS, des bulletins d'associations...) ni forcément passif (on reçoit certes un journal, mais on peut s'abonner à un site lambda et y chercher soi-même ce qu'on veut).